# Easy pie chart is not Working in Flask page

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, easypie

I'm trying to load easy pie chart for my HTML+Flask page and I received only the label without circle.

```
{% block head %}

<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}"/>


{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="overview-chart-body">
            <div class="chart" data-percent="75"><span class="percent">75%</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename ='js/jquery.easypiechart.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.chart').easyPieChart({

            })
        })
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong with this code and how to fix this.

Comment: It doesn't look like a flask question to me. Can you open the inspect in Google Chrome and send the error trace from there?

Comment: This is what error says. Am I imported wrong library ? `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).easyPieChart is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):36)
    at e (VM412 jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at t (VM412 jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2)`